# Smoothly Turn To Direction

Tags: math, rotation, angle, smoothing

I am trying to take angle `A` and smoothly rotate that angle towards angle `B` at a speed of `S` where the speed decreases with the distance between angle `A` and `B`. While angle `A` also turns via the shortest path to angle `B`.

A script I was given as a model for this:

```
Function: rotate_to_destination( A , B , S );
    return ( A + ( sin( ( B - A ) * ( pi / 180 ) ) * S ) );
```

I've been using this and it works great except for a single problem: the time it takes for `A` to turn to `B` is lengthened when the distance between `A` and `B` is exactly 180.

I'm not much for math so I haven't be able to fix the problem or cleverly come up with my own. Nor have I found another solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to know the maximum and minimum difference between A and B. Assuming that 
-180 <= (A-B) <= +180, you can change the formula to `( A + ( sin( ( B - A ) * ( pi / 360 ) ) * S ) );`

Basically, you need to make sure that the term ( B - A ) * ( pi / X ) never goes to zero, pi, -pi, 2*pi, -2*pi, etc, but instead to -pi/2 or pi/2.

Comment: You're a genius. I actually thought of making the term never reach zero. However I instead did:

`return ( A + sign( B - A ) + ( sin( ( B - A ) * ( pi / 180 ) ) * S ) );`

Comment: So answer denied. Did a bit more extensive testing, like I should have. Although your suggestion keeps the angle A from turning in the "closest" direction to angle B.

Comment: Please explain the problem clearly. It also helps if you write the whole code, not only the return part.

Comment: That is the whole Code. Basically A variable holding angle A calls the function inserting it's own angle and the function returns it's angle adjusted bit towards angle B. So each time the function is called angle A is turned towards angle B at speed of S. ~A = rotate_to_dest( A , B , S );~